# pagination issue in mobile responsive device . And showing five rows in desktop, laptop, tablet view. need to display only two rows in mobile device

Tags: javascript, html

Here I have implemented a JavaScript pagination. In my template I have a messages table where I am getting the data dynamically by using Django in backend. So here this pagination is working fine but the issue is in a responsive device. Like in laptop, desktop, tablet the pagination is appearing fine but while I am switching to mobile responsive design pagination is disappearing.
And to solve this issue I just commented meta view port
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
then the pagination is appearing in mobile device.
And also I am displaying five rows in desktop and tablet view i want to show only three rows in mobile device how can we achieve that please help me.

**html template**

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped table-class mytable" id="inbox" style="top:0px;">
        <thead>
        <tr class="msglist_header">
            <th class="fix_member">Member</th>
            <th id="msg_product" class="pro">Product</th>
            <th id="msg_msg" class="nm">Message</th>
            <th id="msg_date">Date</th>
            <th id="msg_Actione">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="inbox-1">
        {% if msg_list %}
        {% for i in msg_list %}
        <tr class="content_set" style="{% if i.flag == 'u' %}font-weight: bold;{% endif %}background-color: white;">
            <td id="texto" style="width: 69px;">
                <div>
                    <a class="fix"href="{% url 'mail_show' i.id %}">{{i.username|first|upper}}
                        <span>{{i.username|last|upper}}</span></a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 214px;">
                <a style="text-decoration:none;color:grey;" href="{% url 'mail_show' i.id %}">
                    <div class="show-form-msgrply a" style="">
                        {{i.ttle}}
                    </div>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 214px;">
                <a style="text-decoration:none;color:grey;" href="{% url 'mail_show' i.id %}">
                    <div id="classi_msg" class="c classi_msg">{{i.message}}</div>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="width:90px;">
                <div class="f">
                    {% for key,value in some_date.items %}
                    {% if i.id == key %}
                    <a style="text-decoration: none;color: black;" href="{% url 'mail_show' i.id %}">{{ value }}</a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:70px;">
                <button class="show-form-msg-delete" style="border:none;outline:none;color:grey;
                                text-align:center;padding:5px;position: relative;top: -6px;">
                    <a style="color:grey" href="{% url 'msg_delete' i.id %}">
                        <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
                    </a>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div> 

**pagination div**
<div id="q-pagination-1"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
// empty list "rows_p"

let rows = []
// Counting number of "rows" (tr) in under table --> under table body(tbody)

$('#inbox tbody tr').each(function(i, row) {
// Then pushing each row into empty list "rows".
    return rows.push(row);
});

// length of list "rows" is less than 31. We are not allowing to show pagination.
if (rows.length < 5){
   $('#q-pagination-1').hide();
}
// For each 30 lines we are prompting pagination in inbox table.

$('#q-pagination-1').pagination({
    dataSource: rows,
    pageSize: 5,

    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        $('#inbox-1').html(data);
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, `screen.width` will give you the width of the screen.

```js
console.log(screen.width)
```

You can use this width and conditionally render your rows according to the screen width of the user's device.
https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/best-screen-size/ - This blog will let you know the most common screen resolutions for web design

Comment: Thanks Salomi for quick response. Yeh I understood about the screen width but in my case in mobile responsive device pagination is not appearing how can we solve that

Comment: Can you share the code in sandbox / codepen ?